# Cannot open config file when installing nagios

Tags: configuration, centos6, installation, nagios, compilation

When trying to setup nagios, I'm running into some errors.

> ```
> Error: Cannot open config file ‘/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg ;new file added ‘ for reading: No such file or directory
> Error processing object config files!
> One or more problems was encountered while processing the config files…
>
> Check your configuration file(s) to ensure that they contain valid
> directives and data definitions. If you are upgrading from a previous
> version of Nagios, you should be aware that some variables/definitions
> may have been removed or modified in this version. Make sure to read
> the HTML documentation regarding the config files, as well as the
> ‘Whats New’ section to find out what has changed.
> ```

My config file is perfect as far as I know, but I can't seem to figure out where the error is coming from.

```
# Define a host for the remote machine
define host{
 use linux-server ; Name of host template to use
 ; This host definition will inherit all variables that are defined
 ; in (or inherited by) the linux-server host template definition.
 host_name nci-helicarrier.nci.nih.gov
 alias CentOS 6.5
 address 128.231.12.230
 }
# Linux host definition template #
define host{
 name linux-server ; The name of this host template
 use generic-host ; This template inherits other values from the generic-host template
 check_period 24×7 ; By default, Linux hosts are checked round the clock
 check_interval 5 ; Actively check the host every 5 minutes
 retry_interval 1 ; Schedule host check retries at 1 minute intervals
 max_check_attempts 10 ; Check each Linux host 10 times (max)
 check_command check-host-alive ; Default command to check Linux hosts
 notification_period workhours ; Linux admins hate to be woken up, so we only notify during the day
 ; Note that the notification_period variable is being overridden from
 ; the value that is inherited from the generic-host template!
 notification_interval 120 ; Resend notifications every 2 hours
 notification_options d,u,r ; Only send notifications for specific host states
 contact_groups admins ; Notifications get sent to the admins by default
 register 1 ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION – ITS NOT A REAL HOST, JUST A TEMPLATE!
 }
```

Even the objects configuration file seems perfect:

```
# OBJECT CONFIGURATION FILE(S)
 # These are the object configuration files in which you define hosts,
 # host groups, contacts, contact groups, services, etc.
 # You can split your object definitions across several config files
 # if you wish (as shown below), or keep them all in a single config file.
# You can specify individual object config files as shown below:
 cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg
 cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/contacts.cfg
 cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/timeperiods.cfg
 cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/templates.cfg
 cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg ;new file added
 cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg ;new file added
# Definitions for monitoring the local (Linux) host
```

I can't seem to find the issue here.

1. the file is readable
2. its labelled right
3. The only thing i changed on it was the (hostname, alias and IP address).

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Comment: Could you please use appropriate formatting of code etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg ;new file added
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/services.cfg ;new file added
```

It seems as if you made the incorrect assumption that you can add a comment to a line using the `;` character. Remove those comments and try again.